# if else loop in an array

Tags: php, arrays, magento, if-statement

I have this following array:

```
   return array(
        $order->getRealOrderId(),
        Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($order->getCreatedAt(), 'medium', true),
        $this->getPaymentMethod($order),
        $this->getShippingMethod($order),
        $this->formatPrice($order->getData('grand_total'), $order),
        $this->getTotalQtyItemsOrdered($order),
        $order->getCustomerName(),
        $order->getCustomerEmail(),
        $this->getStreet($billingAddress),
        $billingAddress->getData("postcode"),
        $billingAddress->getData("telephone"),
    );
```

I want to edit the return value of `getPaymentMethod($order)` and `getShippingMethod($order)`.

`$this->getPaymentMethod($order)` returns, cashondelivery or paypal. I want the text to be changed to "Cash on Collection" if the return value is cashondelivery.

Similarily, `getShippingMethod($order)` returns, Home Delivery (some text here) or Self Collection (some text here). I want to change it to Home Delivery or Self Collection without the extra words. How can I do this within an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->getPaymentMethod($order) == "cashondelivery" ? "Cash On Collection" : "paypal"
```

Maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

you can use `str_replace` function

```
str_replace('cashondelivery', 'Cash on Collection', $this->getPaymentMethod($order));
```

and

```
str_replace('whatever you want to display', 'whatever you want to change', $this->getShippingMethod($order));
```

**documentation** [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: You welcome man, please accept the answer for future people with similar problems!

Comment: The other way is much easier. :)